# Ruby Array changing substring

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to display the following:

```
anu1 cau1 doh1 bef1
```

To do that I need to complete the following Ruby code by adding only ONE statement.

```
 a = ["ant", "cat", "dog", "bee"]
```

Comment: @muistooshort Im learning Ruby, it's an online exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to perform a [**succ**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/String/Nextvalueofastring.htm) function each of the words, which will give you the next value for each of them, then you would just need to append "1" to each.

**Example:** *-Forgive my syntax, Haven't used Ruby in a while-*

```
a.map {|word| word.succ << "1"}
```

**should output:**

```
["anu1", "cau1", "doh1", "bef1"]
```

Comment: `a.collect {|x| print x.next+"1 "}`

This is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["ant", "cat", "dog", "bee"]
# => ["ant", "cat", "dog", "bee"]

a.map {|str| str.succ << "1" }
# => ["anu1", "cau1", "doh1", "bef1"]
```